# Imagem SVG conversão em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, conversão

Tenho uma aplicação em rails e lá eu gerar imagens SVG para retornar para o usuário por e-mail, mas eu quero devolver este em outro formato (png ou jpg). Alguém tem alguma dica sobre como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, vc gera svg e quer converter pra outro formato? É isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo Alex !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a gem mini_magick https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick

Se vc usa Ubuntu, precisa ter o imagemagick e librsvg2-bin instalados

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("input.svg")
image.format "png"
image.write "output.png"
```

Comment: Valeu Alex , vou tentar aqui !